# Roblox - Trying to get InvokeClient Remote Function Working

Tags: roblox

In my server script called MainGameScript I have this code block:

```
local myRemoteFunction = Instance.new("RemoteFunction")
myRemoteFunction.Parent = game.Workspace
myRemoteFunction.Name = "GetBuildInfo"

game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(player)
    print("[MainGameScript] added player") 

    for i,v in pairs(Regions) do
        if (v.Value == 0) then
            Regions[i].Value = player.UserId
            break
        end
    end    

    local success, result = pcall(function() return myRemoteFunction:InvokeClient(player) end)
    if success then
       print(result)
    else
        print("Error calling RemoteFunction GetBuildInfo")
    end
```

end)

I have a LocalScript in game.Workspace called LocalBuildScript which contains this:

```
function game.workspace.GetBuildInfo.OnClientInvoke()
    print("[GetBuildInfo] will send back local build info")
    return "this will be returned to the server caller script"
end
```

The GetBuildInfo function is never called. I have added some debug print lines to the calling function and the process seems to die at the point where it uses pcall... This is almost verbatim the Remote Function Client Invoke example from the Roblox Wiki, no idea why it is not working and am hoping somebody here has some experience using InvokeClient scripts.

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it isn't running is because `LocalScripts` being referenced by `RemoteFunctions` are expected to be inside of the `Player` instance somewhere in it. I'm fairly certain this is the case, as I've implemented a similar test system, but I held my `LocalScript` inside of the `Player` instance.

Comment: Wierd, I originally had it in the MainLocalScript located in PlayerScripts and it didn't work but I was firing the InvokeClient from a different script so maybe that was the issue. Your solution works, thank you.

Comment: LocalScripts only run in very specific locations. They will run if they are descendants of the player, but they can also run inside of a Tool or inside of ReplicatedFirst. The complete list can be found on wiki page: http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/LocalScript